# NSURL Request on Watch OS 2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsurlconnection, watchkit, watchos-2

I just updated Xcode to the latest watch beta and a project that I was working on before now has errors which hadn't been there.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *urlToSet = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/"];
self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:urlToSet]];
(void)[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

The error is on the last line and it says:

```
'initWithRequest:delegate:' is unavailable: not available on watchOS
```

Answer (score 8):

Since `NSURLConnection` is deprecated in iOS9, Apple is forcing everyone to switch to `NSURLSession` and Watch developers are not an exception. So just use the following code instead of yours:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlToSet]];

[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: Thanks! Would the response funtions stay the same?

Comment: Your response logic will look pretty much the same. Just use a completion handler which is passed as an argument instead of a delegate method.